# Angular reusable crud component

Tags: angular, design-patterns, angular-components

I got the mission to build 10 cruds in angular, but I want to create a reusable component for it. I've been thinking if I could separate the components between list and form like below:

E.g.:

[image]

[image]

4 crud's will use live data edition and won't need the form part. In the case with form I will share the data with a service between then.

With this in mind I'm thinking to build a generic component to wrap that behaviour, but in same time, afraid to create a kind of god component hard to maintain and reuse

Have you guys ever did some similar task? Where can I find a good start point for me to base or is there some project where I can get a example?

Comment: You need to explain more, its better if you have a mockup to share. We can always break down components more, but we should understand if we are over-engineering for something which is not really worth it. So, I would ask for more details before commenting on it.

Comment: Ok. The question was edited.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the extent that you have to accomplish (be wary of over-engineering), but if you needed to, you could always base a lot of your needs on inputs and make it pretty re-usable.

I used this [Dynamic forms](https://medium.com/@joshblf/dynamic-nested-reactive-forms-in-angular-654c1d4a769a) site to give me a start on how to create forms from a payload, which may be what you would lean towards. Either way, you can always start off by fulfilling a need of 1 crud and see if you can make it generic through @Input() elements and see where that gets you. Good luck!

Happy coding